# Triggering local notification when certain conditions are met in iOS 10 (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification

I am developing for iOS 10 using Swift 3. I want to make the app fetch data from a remote server silently in the background once in a while and send push notification to the user when new data is available. I know that a remote notification is perhaps the better way to handle this, but is there a way of achieving this locally? I know that I can push notifications at certain time or when user has entered certain locations, but is there a way in which I can trigger the notifications programmatically?

Comment: Have you looked into `Timer` class?

Comment: @Malik I know how to trigger notifications with a timer. The thing is I want to trigger them only when new data is available at the server, instead of at specific times.

Comment: You stated in your question that you want to "fetch data from a remote server silently in the background `once in a while`". How do you define `once in a while`?

Comment: If you already have a way to detect new data from the server, you can just trigger a notification in the function where you get the new data with a really short `UNTimeIntervalTrigger`. However,your question is really vague, please try to go into more details and show the code you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When data arrive you can send a "UILocalNotification" notification. (a Push notifications involves servers, certificates... and so on..)

I suggest:

a) using performFetchWithCompletionHandler

as per ADC:

"When a good opportunity arises, the system WAKES or LAUNCHES your app into the background and calls the app delegate’s application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: method. Use that method to check for new content and initiate a download operation if content is available."

b) in performFetchWithCompletionHandler trigger a download. Pass down the completionHandler to your code that will use NSURL session.

c) when download is done, trigger a LOCAL notifcation, and execute completionHandler iOS has sent you in "performFetchWithCompletionHandler'

as usual note you have strict time constraints..

**Another** way (maybe simpler..) is using backgroundSessionConfiguration/downloadTask.

in call back simply send a local notification.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you very much. Guess the only problem with this approach is that users won't receive notifications if they terminate the app.

Comment: the way is to use Local notification. You You add them, your app will be awaken in future.